# react-router-dom useNavigate() hook, id is not getting set in url path

Tags: javascript, reactjs, navigation, react-router-dom

> I am using react-router-dom v6 for routing purpose. What I am trying to do is passing id in navigate url path

**Following is my onClick method and button code**

```
  let navigate = useNavigate();
  const routeChange = (id) => {
    let path = `${PATH_DASHBOARD.general.ViewActivity}` + id;
    navigate(path);
  };
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
<Button
                          type="submit"
                          variant="contained"
                          sx={{
                            width: "100%",
                            marginTop: 3,
                          }}
                          onClick={() =>
                            routeChange(item.id)
                          }
                        >
                          <Typography variant="body2" align="center">
                            View
                          </Typography>
                        </Button>
```

**Here is my index.js, I am using useRoutes hook**

```
    {
      path: "other",
      element: (
        <AuthGuard>
          <DashboardLayout />
        </AuthGuard>
      ),
      children: [
        {
          path: `/my-activities`,
          element: <MyActivities />,
        },
        {
          path: `/my-activities/view-activity/:id`,
          element: ({ id }) => <ViewActivity id={id} />,
        },
      ],
    }
```

**But when I try to access url is the browser on button click, I am getting this**

```
http://localhost:3000/other/my-activities/view-activity/:id252515
```

**Anyone knows the solution?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are only appending an `id` value to the end of your path string.

Use the `generatePath` utility to inject the `id` value into the `path: "/my-activities/view-activity/:id"` path string.

[generatePath](https://reactrouter.com/docs/en/v6/api#generatepath)

```
import { generatePath, useNavigate } from 'react-router-dom';
```

...

```
const navigate = useNavigate();
const routeChange = (id) => {
  const path = generatePath(PATH_DASHBOARD.general.ViewActivity, { id });
  navigate(path);
};
```

Answer (score 0):

You are just adding `id` value at the end of your path, you should replace it

```
 let path = PATH_DASHBOARD.general.ViewActivity.replace(':id',id);
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
import { generatePath, useNavigate } from 'react-router-dom';

navigate(generatePath(PATH_DASHBOARD.general.ViewActivity, { id }));
```

Look here it is in the documentation: [generatePath](https://reactrouter.com/en/main/utils/generate-path)